# sshd.service: Got notification message from PID, but reception only permitted for main PID

Tags: ssh, fedora

In the past week or so many of our Fedora 25 servers and workstations with the 4.9.x kernel are getting these logs in /var/log/messages:

```
sshd.service: Got notification message from PID xxxx, but reception only
permitted for main PID xxxx: 1 Time(s)
user@xxxx.service: Got notification message from PID xxxx, but reception only
permitted for main PID xxxx: 1 Time(s)
```

Are these of any concern? Could this [old bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1047304) be related? Perhaps this sheds some light?

```
systemctl status -l
● ourdomain
    State: degraded
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 1 units
    Since: Mon 2017-02-13 09:28:47 EST; 2 weeks 2 days ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─user.slice
           │ ├─user-6105.slice
           │ │ ├─session-2159.scope
           │ │ │ ├─10514 systemctl status -l
           │ │ │ ├─26349 sshd: me [priv]
           │ │ │ ├─26376 sshd: me@pts/5
           │ │ │ ├─26377 -bash
           │ │ │ ├─26441 su
           │ │ │ └─26470 bash
           │ │ ├─user@6105.service
           │ │ │ ├─gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7543 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
           │ │ │ ├─at-spi-dbus-bus.service
           │ │ │ │ ├─17460 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
           │ │ │ │ └─17465 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
           │ │ │ ├─dbus.service
           │ │ │ │ ├─ 7382 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
           │ │ │ │ ├─ 7391 /usr/lib64/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
           │ │ │ │ ├─ 7542 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
           │ │ │ │ ├─ 7561 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
           │ │ │ │ ├─ 7594 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
           │ │ │ │ ├─ 7718 /usr/libexec/imsettings-daemon
           │ │ │ │ ├─22486 /usr/libexec/gconfd-2
           │ │ │ │ ├─24823 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon -r --xim
           │ │ │ │ └─24832 /usr/libexec/ibus-dconf
           │ │ │ ├─gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7536 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
           │ │ │ ├─evolution-source-registry.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7516 /usr/libexec/evolution-source-registry
           │ │ │ ├─gvfs-metadata.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7736 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
           │ │ │ ├─gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7547 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
           │ │ │ ├─gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7572 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
           │ │ │ ├─gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7562 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
           │ │ │ ├─init.scope
           │ │ │ │ ├─23030 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
           │ │ │ │ └─23039 (sd-pam)
           │ │ │ ├─tracker-store.service
           │ │ │ │ └─7477 /usr/libexec/tracker-store
           │ │ │ └─gvfs-daemon.service
           │ │ │   ├─7437 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
           │ │ │   ├─7442 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/6105/gvfs -f -o big_writes
           │ │ │   └─7729 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.11 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1427526) in OpenSSH package in Fedora 25.

To the background, the `SD_NOTIFY` was implemented recently (to allow systemd to follow the service status), but the notification is send wrongly also from the per-user processes, which causes this message from systemd.

The fix is already prepared and testing build is available in the bug comments. I will fix that soon as mentioned in the comments. Sorry for the noise.